# MS Word: Element Visible on Top or Bottom of Page Only

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

How can I get an element - a line, a style, or whatever - to show only if it's the first or last line on a page?

Is that even possible?
I don't mean how do I get an element to be absolutely positioned on the top or bottom of the page - I got that one nailed - but what I mean is:

1. If a certain line is the first or last line, it's visible.

or else

2. If it's in the middle of the page, it's invisible (appears as a blank line).

Is this possible?
And, if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

A macro could make something visible at the top or bottom of the page. You would need to run the macro whenever pages changed.

First, the macro would search and make every element invisible, no matter where. Then, starting at the end of the document, the macro would go to the top of the last page, check for the element, and make it visible if there. Then the macro would move up to the bottom of the previous page and check again. Then go the top of the previous page, and continue until reaching the start of the document.

Below is code that jumps to the top of a page, shared by [Allen Wyatt](https://word.tips.net/T000742_Jumping_to_the_Top_of_a_Page.html).

```
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\Page"
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
```